# Unique index with complicated condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have column [Type] in table, which contains Enum value (1,2,4,8 - mix of this numbers).
I need to make unique index for 2 columns with condition ((Type & 8) = 8).

I tried to do this:

```
create unique index [name_unique] on [dbo].[Table]([Name],[SecondName],[Type]) WHERE (Type IN (9,10,12))
```

It works, but i dont want change this index, if i need to add any field to Enum.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, name and version?

Comment: I'm not aware that SQL Server has an enum type.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Enum type in Domain Model. In data base it's only int. I getting value by binary AND

Comment: One solution (though not sure if a good one) is to add computed persisted column to the table with expression `(case when [Type] & 8 <> 8 then [id] else 0 end)` and then add this column to the index. This way all rows with `Type & 8 != 8` will be unique. But may be you'd better use trigger or check constraint calling some function.

Comment: Also, non unique index may help to improve performance of counting non unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use bitwise operators?

```
create unique index [name_unique] on [dbo].[Table]([Name], [SecondName], [Type])
    where ( (AxisType & 8) > 0);
```

Comment: It does not make sense to me that the type in the field list and the type in the condition have different names -- am I missing something?

Comment: @Hogan . . . This is the OPs logic.  It does make sense to me.  Based on a bit being set, the OP wants three columns to be unique in the table.  The fact that one is called `Type` and one called `AxisType` could be a coincidence.

Comment: It was my mistake. AxisType is type. I have corrected my quetstion.  (AxisType & 8) = 1 is not work, because you can't use complicated operation in WHERE state

Comment: @Hogan but your answer does not work, you can't use & in WHERE

Comment: @IlyaPavlov -- This isn't my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Incorrect WHERE clause for filtered index 'name_unique' on table 'dbo.Table'